# How to make a new date-value list by reference to a date list

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time

Here a base date list

```
lstBase={"2018-03-01","2018-03-02","2018-03-03","2018-03-04","2018-03-07","2018-03-08","2018-03-11","2018-03-12","2018-03-13"};
```

and a date-value list

```
lstValue={{"2018-03-01",10},{"2018-03-02",12},{"2018-03-07",23},{"2018-03-13",84}};
```

How to make a new date-value list, and it shall be like this,

```
lstValueNew={{"2018-03-01",10},{"2018-03-02",12},{"2018-03-03",12},{"2018-03-04",12},{"2018-03-07",23},{"2018-03-08",23},{"2018-03-11",23},{"2018-03-12",23},{"2018-03-12",84}};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Find here long-lists tesing-case (right click and save to disk)https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LKTPD/Testcasemma/master/test_to_make_new_date-value_list_20180326.nb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one in the vein of Chris Degnen's, but using `Association` and `Replace` instead of `Increment`:

```
lstBase = {"2018-03-01", "2018-03-02", "2018-03-03", "2018-03-04", 
   "2018-03-07", "2018-03-08", "2018-03-11", "2018-03-12", 
   "2018-03-13"};
lstValue =
  AssociationThread @@ 
   Transpose@{{"2018-03-01", 10}, {"2018-03-02", 12}, {"2018-03-07", 
      23}, {"2018-03-13", 84}};

Module[{cached},
 MapThread[
  {#, Replace[#2, {i : Except[_Missing] :> Set[cached, i], _Missing :>
        cached}]} &,
  {lstBase, Lookup[lstValue, lstBase]}
  ]
 ]

{{"2018-03-01", 10}, {"2018-03-02", 12}, {"2018-03-03", 
  12}, {"2018-03-04", 12}, {"2018-03-07", 23}, {"2018-03-08", 
  23}, {"2018-03-11", 23}, {"2018-03-12", 23}, {"2018-03-13", 84}}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works using list-operations.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[b_, v_] := Module[{p = 1, x = Null},
  (If[# == v[[p, 1]], x = v[[p++, 2]]];
     {#, x}) & /@ b]

lstValueNew = f[lstBase, lstValue]
```

> ```
> {{"2018-03-01", 10}, {"2018-03-02", 12}, {"2018-03-03", 12},
>  {"2018-03-04", 12}, {"2018-03-07", 23}, {"2018-03-08", 23},
>  {"2018-03-11", 23}, {"2018-03-12", 23}, {"2018-03-13", 84}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks! but variable x  be itself in other testing-case.

Comment: @Jerry `x` now isolated as local variable.

Comment: the x appears in the result as “x$21720”

Comment: @Jerry I guess your working data has dates in `lstBase` earlier than the first one in `lstValue`.  Those dates will get a `Null` value with the above edit.

Comment: Yes! the cute code works on the given lists, I hope it also work on this complicated testing-lists https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LKTPD/Testcasemma/master/test_to_make_new_date-value_list_20180326.nb

Answer (score 1):

One could use `TimeSeries` and an appropriate resampling:

```
ts = TimeSeries[{DateObject[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} & /@ lstValue, 
  ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 0}]

lstValueNew = With[{d = DateObject[#]}, {#, ts[d]}] & /@ lstBase
(* {{"2018-03-01", 10}, {"2018-03-02", 12}, {"2018-03-03", 12},
   {"2018-03-04", 12}, {"2018-03-07", 23}, {"2018-03-08", 23}, 
   {"2018-03-11", 23}, {"2018-03-12", 23}, {"2018-03-13", 84}} *)
```

Comment: `TemporalData` objects have the advantage of specifying an interpolation option between time points. This pays big efficiency dividends with multiple sparse time series objects that need subsequent arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks! It works!